# Javascript match URL pattern with special characters allowed

Tags: javascript, regex

My text is:

```
<A HREF="http://ad.doubleclick.net/get/N97638.2534621.INTERSTITIAL/B7532631099.4;sz=1x1;ord=[timestamp]?">
```

I am using the following regex to match URL:

```
var uri_pattern = /\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/ig
```

This works fine, expect that it doesn't catch characters like `[` `]` `?`. I tried manipulating the regex to include special chars, but it didnt seem to work.

For example:

```
var text = '<A HREF="http://ad.doubleclick.net/get/N97638.2534621.INTERSTITIAL/B7532631099.4;sz=1x1;ord=[timemacro]?">';
console.log(text.match(uri_pattern));

//OUTPUT
"http://ad.doubleclick.net/get/N97638.2534621.INTERSTITIAL/B7532631099.4;sz=1x1;ord=[timemacro"
```

Whereas I want:

```
"http://ad.doubleclick.net/get/N97638.2534621.INTERSTITIAL/B7532631099.4;sz=1x1;ord=[timemacro]?"
```

Comment: This might do: `/<a href="([^"]+)"/i`

Comment: @techfoobar The URL might not always be contained inside an anchor tag.

Comment: Ahh.. so you want to catch url patterns, not just href attribute values.. Ok.

Comment: Yes.. the URLs are bit nasty as they may contain trailing special characters..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
var uri_pattern = /\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]|\]|\?))/ig

var text = '<A HREF="http://ad.doubleclick.net/get/N97638.2534621.INTERSTITIAL/B7532631099.4;sz=1x1;ord=[timemacro]?">';

console.log(text.match(uri_pattern));
```

Comment: Works! I saw you removed `\]` and added `|\]|\?` . Can you please briefly explain it?

Comment: Yes . [ and  ? has special meaning in regex . If you want to get these characters out of their action you must use escape character , that is \ . And inside [] don't use \] or \b , it will get other meaning . For more details refer  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions