# Using regex to find a URL that begins with 'www' as well as ends with 'file-path' in a string of text

Tags: javascript, regex

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/RH8f6/52/

```
$('document').ready(function(){
$('#content').each(function(){
    var str = $(this).html();
    var find_url = /(https?:\/\/([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w\/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)/ig;
    var find_email = /([\.\w]+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})/gim;
    var replaced_text = str.replace(find_url, "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>").replace(find_email, '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>');



    $(this).html(replaced_text);

});
});
```

My regex works to find URLs in the text (and convert them to hyperlinks) except for two cases:

1) When the URL begins with 'www'
2) When the URL ends with-a-file-path-that-looks-like-this.

I have no idea how to start solving this. Any tips on what resources I should look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a more complex regular expression to find URLs, such as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21018909/1590612) will solve both of your problems.

To explain why you were having those problems, problem 1 is because your regular expression requires the URL to start with http:// or https://; the portion `https?:\/\/` is not grouped with a question mark to make it optional. The reason for problem 2 is that the allowable characters for the path don't include the minus sign.

Using a pre-built complex regular expression meant to handle many types of URLs is a good bet, banking on someone else's work of trying to handle all possible situations.